# QGIS - field calculator of to calculate the closest point on an arbitrary line

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

Trying to use the field calculator to calculate the closest point on an arbitrary line for each point in an object and append the column to the attribute table. I've had success doing the calculation and mapping the result, but the calculations are not on the attribute table frustratingly. Any ideas?

Comment: how did you do the calculation?

Comment: Closest from what to what? Please be more precise, otherwise it's difficult to help